# DateDiff no esta declarado. Puede que sea inaccesible debido a su nivel de protección

Tags: vb.net, datetime

estoy intentando compilar un simple ejercicio en Visual Basic y no puedo acceder a ciertos métodos de string y date.
Aquí el código:

```
**Sub Main(args As String())

        Dim fecha_Actual As Date = Date.Now

        Dim fecha_Final = New DateTime(2021, 12, 31)

        Console.WriteLine("Tiempo restante en meses: " & DateDiff("m", fecha_Actual, fecha_Final)) 'Linea del error

    End Sub**
```

No puedo acceder al método DateDiff, tampoco puedo hacerlo si importo la librería de datetime.
No tenia este problema en la notebook, pero ahora estoy desde desktop y me ha surgido este inconveniente.

Answer (score 0):

El DateTime No es una Fecha Valida, Además Tienes Mal Puestas las Constantes de DateDiff...

```
Sub Main(args As String())

    Dim fecha_Actual As Date = Date.Now

    Dim fecha_Final As Date = "31/12/2021"

    Console.WriteLine("Tiempo restante en meses: " & DateDiff(DateInterval.Month , fecha_Actual,fecha_Final,FirstDayOfWeek.Monday  ))

End Sub
```